# full linux (not android) 7-inch tablet?

Tags: linux, android

are there any 7-inch tablets that can boot natively into a full version of linux?   I want to remove Android.  All traces of it.  I don't want a jail.  I want to program the hardware fully, without limitations.  from bootup, not with sideloaded linux.  it does not have to be ubuntu touch.

I think pengod shut down.  In a sense, we don't need new hardware.  we need a software flash.  Alibaba is full of cheap 7-inch android tablets in the $50-$100 range.  HP, Toshiba, Hisense, and others are selling them around $120.  can't any of these be flashed into linux of some form or another??  I would be happy to buy more than one of them.  does this kind of device exist?

/iaw

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had an answer as I'm also looking for a way to ditch Android in favor of a true Linux system. Unfortunately most hardware on Android devices run thanks to closed drivers contained in binary blobs. Therefore once you remove Android there goes the underlying hardware support. Probably we have more chances of success with x86 tablets, but at a very different price range for now.